# Can i ignore a max-width in body

Tags: html, css, sass

i want the content on my page to have a max-widht of 2024px, but i want my navbar to span the whole page

Unfortunately I have no idea how to solve it

Comment: Please can you add your html code to better understand the problem?

The way you explained it, it looks like you just need to insert in your css file the code `body {max-width: 2024px;}`

Comment: For a more thorough answer, we'd need to see the HTML markup. In any case, [this article](https://css-irl.info/breaking-out-of-a-central-wrapper/) about breaking out of a confined `max-width` might be useful to you. Also, you might want to consider adding a `<main />` element or a `.wrapper` class to apply the `max-width` rather than applying it directly to the `body`.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the content of your page in a main tag and set the max width of your main to 1024px

```css
main {
  max-width: 1024px;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>Lorem</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      <h1>Lorem</h1>
      <p>Lorem</p>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="" alt="Logo">

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <span>|</span>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <span>|</span>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                    <a href="/">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <span>|</span>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <span>|</span>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>


    <h1 id="main_title">
        Lorem Ipsum
    </h1>

    <p id="main_text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod veritatis, aliquid omnis, autem quaerat culpa consectetur provident dicta repellat numquam eveniet distinctio. Accusantium exercitationem eos nam quia odit ipsa reprehenderit?
    </p>

</body>
</html>
```

```scss
body {
    background-color: #242424;
    max-width: 1024px;
}


header {
    z-index: 99;
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: #242424;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 20px #000000;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    backdrop-filter: blur(25px);
    
    img {
        width: 100px;
        padding: .75rem
    }

    nav {
        margin: 0 3rem 0 0;

        ul {
            li {
                display: inline;
                list-style-type: none;
                padding: 0 .5rem 0 .5rem;

                a {
                    font-size: 1.3rem;
                    transition: 2s;

                    ::hover {
                        transform: translateX(10px);
                    }
                }
                span {
                    font-size: 1.5rem;
                    color: #fff;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your original post and add your code there, instead of an answer. Be sure to use the snippet that have <> as an icon in the menu.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).